# JavaFX, apply setStyle to all LineCharts in ObservableList

Tags: javafx-2, observablecollection, linechart

I have `ObservableList<LineChart> backCharts`. Also I have class StackChartSeries to compare data's scale. Depending on that I add new backchart with new scale or add series to existed backchart. 
Applying style to chart must work with every chart of the specified scale. But it works only with the first chart of the specified scale.

Code next:

```
    public class StackChart extends StackPane {

    private  LineChart baseChart;
    private final ObservableList<LineChart> backCharts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private final double yAxisWidth = 60;
    private final AnchorPane details;

    private final double yAxisSeparation = 20;
    private double strokeWidth = 0.5;
    private int size = 0;

    public StackChart(LineChart baseChart) {
        this(baseChart, null);
    }

    public StackChart(LineChart baseChart, Double strokeWidth) {
        if (strokeWidth != null) {
            this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        }
        this.baseChart = baseChart;
        baseChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        baseChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        baseChart.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(false);
        baseChart.getXAxis().setAnimated(false);
        baseChart.getXAxis().setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + 18);
        baseChart.getYAxis().setAnimated(false);
        baseChart.getYAxis().setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + 18);

        setFixedAxisWidth(baseChart);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        backCharts.addListener((Observable observable) -> rebuildChart());

        details = new AnchorPane();
        bindMouseEvents(baseChart, this.strokeWidth);

        rebuildChart();
    }

    private void bindMouseEvents(LineChart baseChart, Double strokeWidth) {
        getChildren().add(details);
        details.prefHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        details.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        details.setMouseTransparent(true);

        setOnMouseMoved(null);
        setMouseTransparent(false);

        final Axis xAxis = baseChart.getXAxis();
        final Axis yAxis = baseChart.getYAxis();

        final Line xLine = new Line();
        final Line yLine = new Line();
        yLine.setFill(Color.GRAY);
        xLine.setFill(Color.GRAY);
        yLine.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth/2);
        xLine.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth/2);
        xLine.setVisible(false);
        yLine.setVisible(false);

        final Node chartBackground = baseChart.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        for (Node n: chartBackground.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()) {
            if (n != chartBackground && n != xAxis && n != yAxis) {
                n.setMouseTransparent(true);
            }
        }
        chartBackground.setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
        chartBackground.setOnMouseEntered((event) -> {
            chartBackground.getOnMouseMoved().handle(event);
            xLine.setVisible(true);
            yLine.setVisible(true);
            details.getChildren().addAll(xLine, yLine);
        });
        chartBackground.setOnMouseExited((event) -> {
            xLine.setVisible(false);
            yLine.setVisible(false);
            details.getChildren().removeAll(xLine, yLine);
        });
        chartBackground.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
            double x = event.getX() + chartBackground.getLayoutX();
            double y = event.getY() + chartBackground.getLayoutY();

            xLine.setStartX(65);
            xLine.setEndX(details.getWidth()-10);
            xLine.setStartY(y+5);
            xLine.setEndY(y+5);

            yLine.setStartX(x+5);
            yLine.setEndX(x+5);
            yLine.setStartY(12);
            yLine.setEndY(details.getHeight()-28);
        });
    }

    private void setFixedAxisWidth(LineChart chart) {
        chart.getYAxis().setPrefWidth(yAxisWidth);
        chart.getYAxis().setMaxWidth(yAxisWidth);
    }

    private void rebuildChart() {
        getChildren().clear();

        getChildren().add(resizeBaseChart(baseChart));
        for (LineChart lineChart : backCharts) {
            getChildren().add(resizeBackgroundChart(lineChart));
        }
        getChildren().add(details);
    }

    private Node resizeBaseChart(LineChart lineChart) {
        HBox hBox = new HBox(lineChart);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hBox.prefHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        hBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());

        lineChart.minWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth+yAxisSeparation)*backCharts.size()));
        lineChart.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth+yAxisSeparation)*backCharts.size()));
        lineChart.maxWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth+yAxisSeparation)*backCharts.size()));

        return lineChart;
    }

    private Node resizeBackgroundChart(LineChart lineChart) {
        HBox hBox = new HBox(lineChart);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hBox.prefHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
        hBox.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        hBox.setMouseTransparent(true);

        lineChart.minWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth + yAxisSeparation) * backCharts.size()));
        lineChart.prefWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth + yAxisSeparation) * backCharts.size()));
        lineChart.maxWidthProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract((yAxisWidth + yAxisSeparation) * backCharts.size()));

        lineChart.translateXProperty().bind(baseChart.getYAxis().widthProperty());
        lineChart.getYAxis().setTranslateX((yAxisWidth + yAxisSeparation) * backCharts.indexOf(lineChart));

        return hBox;
    }

    private LineChart prepareLineChart(String seriesName){
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();

        // xAxis
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setVisible(false);
        xAxis.setOpacity(0.0);
        xAxis.lowerBoundProperty().bind(((NumberAxis) baseChart.getXAxis()).lowerBoundProperty());
        xAxis.upperBoundProperty().bind(((NumberAxis) baseChart.getXAxis()).upperBoundProperty());
        xAxis.tickUnitProperty().bind(((NumberAxis) baseChart.getXAxis()).tickUnitProperty());

        // yAxis
        yAxis.setSide(Side.RIGHT);
        yAxis.setLabel(seriesName);

        // create chart
        LineChart lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setAnimated(false);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);

        setFixedAxisWidth(lineChart);

        return lineChart;
    }

    public void addSeries(List<StackChartSeries> series){
        Collections.sort(series, (x, y) -> (int) (x.getMaxY() - y.getMaxY()));

        LineChart lineChart = null;
        size = series.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || series.get(i).getMaxY() / series.get(i-1).getMaxY() >= 10
                    || series.get(i).getMaxY() / series.get(i-1).getMaxY() <= 0.1
                    || Math.abs(series.get(i).getMaxY() - series.get(i-1).getMaxY()) >= 900
                    )   {
                lineChart = prepareLineChart("Scale" + i);
                //new chart with new scale
                backCharts.add(lineChart);
            }
            lineChart.getData().add(series.get(i).getSeries());
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (LineChart chart : backCharts) {
            styleBackChart(chart);
            //HERE
            setLineStyle(chart, j+3);
        }
    }

    private void styleBackChart(LineChart lineChart) {
        setStyle(lineChart);

        Node contentBackground = lineChart.lookup(".chart-content").lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        contentBackground.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");//

        lineChart.setVerticalZeroLineVisible(false);
        lineChart.setHorizontalZeroLineVisible(false);
        lineChart.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + 18);
        lineChart.getYAxis().setStyle("-fx-font-size:" + 18);
        }

    private void setStyle(LineChart chart) {
        chart.getYAxis().lookup(".axis-label").setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24;");
        Node seriesLine = chart.lookup(".chart-series-line");
        seriesLine.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width: " + strokeWidth + ";");
    }

    public Node getLegend() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();

        final CheckBox baseChartCheckBox = new CheckBox(baseChart.getYAxis().getLabel());
        baseChartCheckBox.setSelected(true);
        baseChartCheckBox.setDisable(true);
        baseChartCheckBox.getStyleClass().add("readonly-checkbox");
        baseChartCheckBox.setOnAction(event -> baseChartCheckBox.setSelected(true));
        hbox.getChildren().add(baseChartCheckBox);

        for (final LineChart lineChart : backCharts) {
            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(lineChart.getYAxis().getLabel());
            checkBox.setSelected(true);
            checkBox.setOnAction(event -> {
                if (backCharts.contains(lineChart)) {
                    backCharts.remove(lineChart);
                } else {
                    backCharts.add(lineChart);
                }
            });
            hbox.getChildren().add(checkBox);
        }

        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setSpacing(20);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-padding: 0 10 20 10");

        return hbox;
    }

    private void setLineStyle (LineChart chart, Integer k)   {
        Node seriesLine = chart.lookup(".chart-series-line");
        seriesLine.setStyle(" -fx-stroke-dash-array: " + k + " 5 15 5;");
    }
}
```

StackChartSeries.java:

```
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Optional;

public class StackChartSeries {
    private XYChart.Series series;
    private final double[] xValues;
    private final double[] yValues;
    private Optional<Double> maxY;

    public StackChartSeries(double[] xValues, double[] yValues) {
        this.xValues = xValues;
        this.yValues = yValues;
    }

    public XYChart.Series getSeries() {
        return series != null ? series : (series = prepareSeries(xValues, yValues));
    }

    private static XYChart.Series<Number, Number> prepareSeries( double[] xValues, double[] yValues)   {
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++){
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(xValues[i], yValues[i]));
        }
        return series;
    }

    public double getMaxY(){
        if (maxY != null){
            return maxY.get();
        }
        else {
            Double d = C?ollections.max(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(yValues)));
            maxY = Optional.of(d);
            return maxY.get();
        }
    }

    public double[] getXValues() {
        return xValues;
    }

    public double[] getYValues() {
        return yValues;
    }
}
```

Comment: I decided it. It must be next:

private void setLineStyle (LineChart chart, Integer k)   {
        Set<Node> seriesLine = chart.lookupAll(".chart-series-line");
        for (Node node : seriesLine) {
            node.setStyle(" -fx-stroke-dash-array: " + k + " 5 15 5;");
        }
    }